# C# Open Url and download a file, the last part of the file name changes

Tags: url

I want to download a file from an URL, the file name is updated frequently
For E.g.: filename_Date.zip where date changes.

Below is the Query I used

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPPES_Deactivated_NPI_Report_081214.zip", @"C:\Users\gnanasem\Documents\NPIMatcher\NPI.zip");

Landing Page of the URL: http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPI_Files.html
Here you can see multiple files and I want to download the first one.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to:

1. Get the HTML of the webpage
2. Find the URLs on the webpage using RegEx
3. Find the first URL containing the relevant text, in your case "Deactivated"
4. Download the file

I got it working like this:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    var websiteHtml = webClient.DownloadString("http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPI_Files.html");

    var urlPattern = "href\\s*=\\s*(?:[\"'](?<1>[^\"']*)[\"']|(?<1>\\S+))";
    Match match = Regex.Match(websiteHtml, urlPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    var urlToDownload = string.Empty;

    while (match.Success)
    {
        var urlFound = match.Groups[1].Value;

        if (urlFound.ToLower().Contains("deactivated"))
        {
            urlToDownload = urlFound;
            break;
        }

        match = match.NextMatch();
    }

    webClient.DownloadFile(urlToDownload, @"C:\Users\gnanasem\Documents\NPIMatcher\NPI.zip");
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I did to solve the case, Thanks a lot for sharing this.